# MVC Core - Get value from a static method into View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have edited my question to make it more clear:

I have website with ads listing page, where multiple ads are listed by category. Currently along with other information the page displays the exact DateTime ad was submitted to website.

Now, I also want to display the number of hours or days or weeks ad been on the website.

**Example:**

```
Ad was posted 2 days ago 
Ad was posted 1 week ago etc
```

Similar to what you see at the end of each comment posted on StackOverflow i.e:

```
– Stephen Muecke 5 hours ago
– Jilani pasha 4 hours ago
- Stephen Muecke 36 mins ago
```

I have already written a method that takes Ad posting DateTime and returns the hours or days or weeks.

What I want to know is how to call and pass value (Ad posting date) to that method from my view?
Or What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: While your can, you should not. Do it in the controller and pass the calculated value to your view via a view model.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke how can we implement to refresh the time by itself in view ...like we see in stackoverflow....

Comment: You mean the way the _asked 42 mins ago_ updates? - that would be just using javascript (with a timer event)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke yes, then may be javascript (with a timer event) will solve this question..but here timer should start from Model.AdPostedDateTime....

Comment: @Jilanipasha, That's correct (and if you inspect the page source for this page you will see `<span title="someDateTimeValue" class="relativetime">`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need to display the time (hours/days/weeks etc) in ads listing page, where multiple ads are listed by category. So what's the best possible solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean the days/hours etc since the add was first listed (perhaps if you edit your question to include a sample of the data and how you want to display on the page it would make it easier to understand)

Comment: The answer you accepted is not only crazy (your view model should just have a property for the 'time' and you set in in the controller using your static method, but more importantly it does not update

Comment: @StephenMuecke adding the method in ViewModel worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static HtmlHelper function :

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetAddedDate<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, DateTime creationDate)
    {
        var str = YourFunction(creationDate);
        return new MvcHtmlString(str);
    }
}
```

Called in view by :  `@Html.GetAddedDate(Model.CreationDate)`

Or you can add a method in your ViewModel/Model like :

```
public class MyAd {
    public int Id;
    public DateTime CreationDate;
    public string GetCreationDate() {
         return YourFunction(CreationDate);
    }
}
```

Called in view by :

```
@foreach(var model in Model) {
    <text>@model.GetCreationDate();</text>
}
```